# Handling error on clicking cancel in htaccess authentication

Tags: .htaccess

I have written a .htaccess file and I am able to authenticate a the username and password correctly. But when I click cancel during the htaccess authentication, I get an "Access Error - Unauthorized" or a server error message.

firstly I am not sure what the error code is. I tried the following

```
ErrorDocument 400 /400.html
```

I also tried with the error codes 401, 403, 404, 500 but still that error persists.

My htacess file looks like this.. I have used the < files > tag to enforce the authentication for different html files.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "prompt"
AuthUserFile /.htpasswd
Require user mike
```

Do I need to place the "ErrorDocument" for every html file that I am trying to protect or just one "ErrorDocument" statement at the end would suffice for all the files that I am trying to protect..?

Comment: I don't really understand what is the problem here... What do you want to happen, when user cancels authentication and enters as *Unauthorised*?

Comment: No. When user cancels the authentication, I see the error page..

Comment: There is no answer "*No*" to question beginning with "*What*". I understand what you see, but I have no idea what you would like to see instead.

Comment: Sorry.. I meant "no he doesn't enter as unauthorised". Just replied carelessly. Anyway, all I want to see  is some text which I have entered in the 400.html file.

Answer (score 1):

There are two rules you may have forgotten.

1. The error page itself must **not** be protected by .htaccess. It must be reachable.
2. The path to the `ErrorDocument` files counts from document root.

If you obey the rules, the code works (just tested it). This is what my sucessfull test involved:

#### Files:

> /protected/.htaccess
> /protected/.htpasswd
> /401.php

#### .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile protected/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```